# Bootstrap FileUpload empty array after clear

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, jasny-bootstrap

You can see the problem here http://bmi.sf.net/test.html.

For exact code I am using, right click on this website and select `View source` in menu.

I am using Jasny bootstrap fileupload plugin. I have a form in which this plugin is used. The form submits to a php file in which the $_FILES array is manipulated.

In the code above I have used jQuery form plugin to view live preview of form submission. The php is just doing one thing: `print_r($_FILES)`

It is working great except when the following series of action occurs, the $_FILES array is empty:

- The user selects a file. Shows normal php output.
- Then user clears the form using 'x' button. Shows empty array as expected.
- The user loads a new file. Now the array is empty against expectation.

How to fix this?

If user does not clear form first but loads a new file directly then array is not empty. However every user will not do this so I want to solve the given problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a race condition. The fileupload plugin clears the name of the `<input type="file">` and sets an `<input type="hidden">` to tell the server the difference between pressing clear or submit without a change in a normal form. However in your case, you don't want this behaviour.

For a quick and dirty fix, always set the name of the `<input type="file">` on change.

```
$('#filep').on('change', function() { $(this).attr('name', 'filep') });
```